# ConnectionRefusedError No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-python-driver

I was trying to reconnect with the a local instance, but getting this error, what can be the possible workaround?
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:8000': ConnectionRefusedError(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 6000)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})

my docker-compose.yml file looks like this
networks:
app-tier:
driver: bridge

services:
cassandra:
image: 'cassandra:latest'
networks:
- app-tier
expose:
- '6000'
ports:
- '6000:9042'

Answer (score 0):

Your client tries to connect to a port `8000` while you are exposing port `6000`. Change port settings.